# Cannot find name 'exports' error in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a typescript file like below,

**Environment.ts**

```
var Environment = "DEV"
exports.Environment = Environment;
```

And I am using it in my app.config file like below,

```
var execEnv = require('./src/execEnvironment.ts');
```

which gives me the error

> cannot find name 'exports'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Use "standarized" ES6 style exports which are supported by Typescript

**environment.ts**

```
export const Environment = "DEV"
```

**app.config.ts**

```
import {Environment} from './environment'  // <= no .ts at the end
```

You can even rename on import

```
import {Environment as execEnv} from './environment'
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

**environment.ts** file

```
export const environment = {
    production: false
};
```

**app.config.ts**

```
var execEnv = require('./src/execEnvironment.ts');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`export var Environment = 'DEV';`

instead of 
`var Environment = "DEV"
exports.Environment = Environment;`